# Fabricjs performance with many objects on canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm checking out fabricjs to see if its suitable for rendering diagrams on canvas. Performance is one of the key issue we are concerned about. In a prototype I just built, the canvas become kind of not responding when I add around 3500 objects to it. It can render in around 4~5 seconds, but selecting a circle and dragging it around is super slow.

I'm wondering if it is expected or just I'm doing it wrong.

The prototype is just a graph with circle as the vertex and line as the edge. Each line would have a small triangle at the end to indicate direction. So overall the canvas would have like 6500 objects on it.

Comment: This is to be expected. Create an additional canvas that has a copy of the drawing. You render that as the background image. When the user selects an item, set the clip only where the object is, clear and rerender and don't render the item. The item can be rendered on the onscreen canvas. When the operation is complete you can then just render the item back to the background. Objects that are clipped out will not take as much time to render so the background will render quicker. This way you can manipulate the item in realtime while still having the bacground.

Comment: I would say it would be expected. The objects would have to be cached to bitmaps to avoid constant rasterization. If you could do this in fabricjs I don't know, but if cached you could probably do about 2-3x as many. If they can be cached also depends on how the objects are displayed of course..

Comment: My 2-cents. Yes, expect considerable lagging if you have 6500 "smart" items, & Yes, cache the base item for better performance. **But** ... 6500 items ... !??  If you're really concerned about performance then **don't even try to display 6500 items at once!**. It's not that it can't be done, but won't the user experience be just as good with, say, <1000 items?

Comment: @Blindman67, thanks for the tip, will try if this helps.

Comment: @markE But we are planning to do such a thing. Will the WebGL renderer help us out?

Comment: @Yeling I don't think FabricJS yet supports rendering in 3D-WebGL, but last time I looked it's on Kangax's TODO list. But yes, WebGL will likely render your circle-line-triangle items much more quickly than 2D Canvas.

Comment: webgl is not really near. i'm starting webgl for image filtering just now. What could help you is object caching for sure, but even if you would implement object caching and dirty rects, looping trought 6500 items just to see wich one touch the active one is not so fast. Are elements of this graph grouped someway?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, what we are really trying to do visualize a possibly very large graph, maybe even with millions of vertices, such as a social network. We could add some course grained layers for grouped elements, but I think we will need to render 500 vertices smoothly and still stay responsive.

Comment: @Yeling. 500 items can be drawn on the canvas very quickly. About your word "responsive": Are the 500 items static and if not, how would the user interact with the items?

Comment: @markE, those items are not static, use should be able to select them and at least drag them around. The bottom line is something like this:  [D3 force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)